# Duplicate class conflict in Android studio

Tags: java, android, apache, jar

When migrating to androidx I found some conflict of modules `httpmime-4.0.1.jar` with `httpmime-4.3.6.jar`.

I tried some codes in gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.links.meplinks"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 29
        versionName "1.15.11"
        multiDexEnabled true

        android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
        android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/hani-momanii/maven" }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'



    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module:'httpmime-4.0.1'
    }


}
```

> Duplicate class org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart found in
>   modules httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart found in modules
>   httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart$1 found in modules
>   httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode found in modules
>   httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.MIME found in modules httpmime-4.0.1.jar
>   (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.MinimalField found in modules
>   httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity found in modules
>   httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody found in
>   modules httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody found in modules
>   httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody found in modules
>   httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody found in modules
>   httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody found in modules
>   httpmime-4.0.1.jar (httpmime-4.0.1.jar) and httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6)
>
> Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution
>   errors.

Comment: Look at the last line of your error message - It's saying `Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the `httpmime` to `4.5.6` and exclude the `httpcore-4.4.10` module

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
implementation ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6'){
     exclude module: 'httpclient'
     exclude module:'httpcore-4.4.10'
}
```